# Emulator with Firebase Only Runs On Home Wifi (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, android-emulator, firebase-realtime-database, android-wifi

I'm having an issue when it comes to running my emulator on my laptop when I'm on different networks. When logging in and registering within the app, I can only seem to write and read data from my Firebase Database when I'm connected to my home Wifi (the original location where the app was created).

Is there something I'm supposed to add to my app to allow for it to connect to other Wifi networks?

Is it maybe that I can only test the app on other networks using a real device?